# Using CSS transform scale() to zoom into an element without cropping, maintaining scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms, scaletransform

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/b8vLg0ny/

It's possible to use the CSS `scale` and `translate` functions to zoom into element.

Take this example, of 4 boxes in a 2x2 grid.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="zoom-container">
    <div class="box red">A</div>
    <div class="box blue">B</div>
    <div class="box green">C</div>
    <div class="box black">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; }

body, html { height: 100%; }

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#zoom-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.red { background: red; }
.blue { background: blue; }
.green { background: green; }
.black { background: black; }
```

JavaScript:

```
window.zoomedIn = false;

$(".box").click(function(event) {
  var el = this;
  var zoomContainer = $("#zoom-container");

  if (window.zoomedIn) {
    console.log("resetting zoom");
    zoomContainer.css("transform", "");
    $("#container").css("overflow", "auto");
    window.zoomedIn = false;
  } else {
    console.log("applying zoom");
    var top = el.offsetTop;
    var left = el.offsetLeft - 0.25*zoomContainer[0].clientWidth;

    var translateY = 0.5*zoomContainer[0].clientHeight - top;
    var translateX = 0.5*zoomContainer[0].clientWidth - left;

    $("#container").css("overflow", "scroll");
    zoomContainer.css("transform", "translate(" + 2 * translateX + "px, " + 2 * translateY + "px) scale(2)");
    window.zoomedIn = true;
  }
});
```

By controlling the value of `translateX` and `translateY`, you can change how the zooming works.

The initial rendered view looks something like this:

[image: initial rendered view]

Clicking on the A box will zoom you in appropriately:

[image: zooming to A and then zooming out]

(Note that clicking D at the end is just showing the reset by zooming back out.)

**The problem is**: zooming to box D will scale the zoom container such that scrolling to the top and left doesn't work, because the contents overflow. The same happens when zooming to boxes B (the left half is cropped) and C (the top half is cropped). Only with A does the content not overflow outside the container.

In similar situations related to scaling (see [CSS3 Transform Scale and Container with Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17757967/528044)), one possible solution is to specify `transform-origin: top left` (or `0 0`). Because of the way the scaling works relative to the top left, the scrolling functionality stays. That doesn't seem to work here though, because it means you're no longer repositioning the contents to be focused on the clicked box (A, B, C or D).

Another possible solution is to add a `margin-left` and a `margin-top` to the zoom container, which adds enough space to make up for the overflowed contents. But again: the translate values no longer line up.

So: is there a way to *both* zoom in on a given element, *and* overflow with a scroll so that contents aren't cropped?

**Update**: There's a rough almost-solution by animating `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft`, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406704/528044 (see [the jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rheo6o7p/1/)), but it's not quite a proper solution because it first zooms to the top left, not the intended target. I'm beginning to suspect this isn't actually possible, because it's probably equivalent to asking for `scrollLeft` to be negative.

Comment: If I say, all the boxes gets zoomed in but the one clicked should be in view, right?, and then, by scrolling, one can move to any of the boxes, right?

Comment: Clicking a box should zoom in on the clicked box. It should then be possible to scroll to any of the other boxes to bring them into view.

Comment: I am working little-by-little with this, got this far, https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/b8vLg0ny/5/ ... and I might offer a bounty when possible (2 days after posting), to give more attraction to your question as I think it is a good one, and I also have an interest in a similar solution

Comment: I've updated my question with a link to http://stackoverflow.com/a/31406704/528044 which has a rough half-solution but the animation timing is a bit clunky.

Comment: There was another similar question I encountered before that you might find helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196639/zooming-in-overflow-scroll My own answer over there can't satisfy all of your requirements though.

Comment: @AVAVT Hope you don't mind me added a link to that post in my answer. I find it interesting and as comment can disappear, now this link won't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just to reposition the `TransformOrigin` to `0 0` and to use proper `scrollTop/scrollLeft` **after** the animation?

- <del>https://jsfiddle.net/b8vLg0ny/7/</del>
- ***Updated:***  https://jsfiddle.net/b8vLg0ny/13/

*If you do not need the animation, the `TransformOrigin` can always stays `0 0` and only the scrolling is used to show the box.*

To make the animation less jumpy use transition only for `transform` porperty, otherwise the `transform-origin` gets animated also. I have edited the example with `4x4` elements, but I think it makes sense to zoom a box completely into view, thats why I changed the zoom level.  But if you stay by zoom level 2 and the grid size `15x15` for instance, then with this approach really precise origin should be calculated for transform, and then also the correct scrolling.

Anyway I don't know, if you find this approach useful.

Stack snippet

```js
var zoomedIn = false;
var zoomContainer = $("#zoom-container");

$(".box").click(function(event) {
  var el = this;
  
  if (zoomedIn) {    
    zoomContainer.css({
     transform: "scale(1)",
      transformOrigin: "0 0"
    });
    zoomContainer.parent().scrollTop(0).scrollLeft(0);
    zoomedIn = false;
    return;
  } 
  zoomedIn = true;
  var $el = $(el);
  animate($el);
  zoomContainer.on('transitionend', function(){
   zoomContainer.off('transitionend');
   reposition($el);
  })
});

var COLS = 4, ROWS = 4, 
   COLS_STEP = 100 / (COLS - 1), ROWS_STEP = 100 / (ROWS - 1),
    ZOOM = 4;
  

function animate($box) {
  var cell = getCell($box);
  var col =  cell.col * COLS_STEP + '%',
      row =  cell.row * ROWS_STEP + '%';
  zoomContainer.parent().css('overflow', 'hidden');
 zoomContainer.css({
    transition: 'transform 0.2s ease-in-out',
   transform: "scale(" + ZOOM + ")",
    transformOrigin: col + " " + row
  });
}
function reposition($box) {
  zoomContainer.css({
    transition: 'none',
   transform: "scale(" + ZOOM + ")",
    transformOrigin: '0 0'
  });  
  zoomContainer.parent().css('overflow', 'auto');
  $box.get(0).scrollIntoView();
}
function getCell ($box) {
 var idx = $box.index();
  var col = idx % COLS,
      row =  (idx / ROWS) | 0;
  return { col: col, row: row };
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; }

body, html { height: 100%; }

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#zoom-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  will-change: transform;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;  
}

.red { background: red; }
.blue { background: blue; }
.green { background: green; }
.black { background: black; }
.l { opacity: .3 }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="zoom-container">
    <div class="box red">A</div>
    <div class="box blue">B</div>
    <div class="box green">C</div>
    <div class="box black">D</div>

    <div class="box red l">E</div>
    <div class="box blue l">F</div>
    <div class="box green l">G</div>
    <div class="box black l">H</div>

    <div class="box red">I</div>
    <div class="box blue">J</div>
    <div class="box green">K</div>
    <div class="box black">L</div>

    <div class="box red l">M</div>
    <div class="box blue l">N</div>
    <div class="box green l">O</div>
    <div class="box black l">P</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mostly because whenever I've tried this, it seems to break down for large grids (say, 10x10, or 15x15). For example, this seems really jumpy to me when clicking boxes in the bottom right area: https://jsfiddle.net/b8vLg0ny/9/ (although I admit I could be missing something in the JS where I've not updated enough values). The animation that zooms into `0 0` ends up out of sync with the scroll animation.

Comment: @AdamPrescott After _tenbits_ update, does it now work as you would like to? ... Asking because I don't see any point in improve mine further as this once is great.

Comment: This looks like the best possible solution!

Answer (score 1):

Update

I got stuck on scroll bars not showing all the time, so I need to investigating that part, so that code is commented out and instead I use a delay to move the clicked box into view.

Here is [my fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/b8vLg0ny/3/), which I use to play with, to figure out how to solve the scroll bar issue.

*Side note: In a comment made by @AVAVT, I would like to link to [his post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196639/zooming-in-overflow-scroll), as that might help someone else, which I find as an interesting alternative in some cases.*

```js
(function(zoomed) {
  
  $(".box").click(function(event) {
    
    var el = this, elp = el.parentElement;
    
    if (zoomed) {
      zoomed = false;
      $("#zoom-container").css({'transform': ''});
      
    } else {
      zoomed = true;
      /*  this zooms correct but show 1 or none scroll for B,C,D so need to figure out why
      
      var tro = (Math.abs(elp.offsetTop - el.offsetTop) > 0) ? 'bottom' : 'top';
      tro += (Math.abs(elp.offsetLeft - el.offsetLeft) > 0) ? ' right' : ' left';
      $("#zoom-container").css({'transform-origin': tro, 'transform': 'scale(2)'});
      */
      
      $("#zoom-container").css({'transform-origin': '0 0', 'transform': 'scale(2)'});
      /* delay needed before scroll into view */      
      setTimeout(function() {
        el.scrollIntoView();
      },250);
    }    
  });
})();
```

```css
* { margin: 0; }

body, html { height: 100%; }

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#zoom-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.red {
  background: red; 
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
.black {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="zoom-container">
    <div class="box red">A</div>
    <div class="box blue">B</div>
    <div class="box green">C</div>
    <div class="box black">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. Compare clicking D in my original example to clicking D in this one. They don't align properly, so the positions are off. Similarly with B: it's off by half the width of the view.

Comment: @AdamPrescott Yes, you'll have to adjust that, I didn't, just showed how to get both scroll bars and zoom.

Comment: Sure. It does zoom, but on the wrong part, which is the main issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question, since I'm fairly confident that it's actually not possible with the given requirements. At least not without some hackery that would cause problems visually, e.g., jumpy scrolling by animating `scrollTop` after switching `transform-origin` to `0, 0` (which removes the cropping by bringing everything back into the container).

I'd love for someone to prove me wrong, but it seems equivalent to asking for `scrollLeft = -10`, something that [MDN will tell you is not possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft). ("If set to a value less than 0 [...], scrollLeft is set to 0.")

If, however, it's acceptable to **change the UI from scrolling, to zooming and dragging/panning**, then it's achievable: https://jsfiddle.net/jegn4x0f/5/

Here's the solution with the same context as my original problem:

[image: zoom-pan]

HTML:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="zoom-out">Zoom out</button>

<div id="container">
  <div id="inner-container">
    <div id="zoom-container">
      <div class="box red">A</div>
      <div class="box blue">B</div>
      <div class="box green">C</div>
      <div class="box black">D</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//
// credit for the approach goes to
//
//   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252249/move-drag-pan-and-zoom-object-image-or-div-in-pure-js#comment58224460_35253567
//
// and the corresponding example:
//
//  https://jsfiddle.net/j8kLz6wm/1/
//

// in a real-world setting, you
// wouldn't keep this information
// on window. this is just for
// the demonstration.
window.zoomedIn = false;

// stores the initial translate values after clicking on a box
window.translateY = null;
window.translateX = null;

// stores the incremental translate values based on
// applying the initial translate values + delta
window.lastTranslateY = null;
window.lastTranslateX = null;

// cursor position relative to the container, at
// the time the drag started
window.dragStartX = null;
window.dragStartY = null;

var handleDragStart = function(element, xCursor, yCursor) {
  window.dragStartX = xCursor - element.offsetLeft;
  window.dragStartY = yCursor - element.offsetTop;

  // disable transition animations, since we're starting a drag
  $("#zoom-container").css("transition", "none");
};

var handleDragEnd = function() {
  window.dragStartX = null;
  window.dragStartY = null;
  // remove the individual element's styling for transitions
  // which brings back the stylesheet's default of animating.
  $("#zoom-container").css("transition", "");

  // keep track of the translate values we arrived at
  window.translateY = window.lastTranslateY;
  window.translateX = window.lastTranslateX;
};

var handleDragMove = function(xCursor, yCursor) {
  var deltaX = xCursor - window.dragStartX;
  var deltaY = yCursor - window.dragStartY;

  var translateY = window.translateY + (deltaY / 2);
  // the subtracted value here is to keep the letter in the center
  var translateX = window.translateX + (deltaX / 2) - (0.25 * $("#inner-container")[0].clientWidth);

  // fudge factor, probably because of percentage
  // width/height problems. couldn't really trace down
  // the underlying cause. hopefully the general approach
  // is clear, though.
  translateY -= 9;
  translateX -= 4;

  var innerContainer = $("#inner-container")[0];

  // cap all values to prevent infinity scrolling off the page
  if (translateY > 0.5 * innerContainer.clientHeight) {
    translateY = 0.5 * innerContainer.clientHeight;
  }

  if (translateX > 0.5 * innerContainer.clientWidth) {
    translateX = 0.5 * innerContainer.clientWidth;
  }

  if (translateY < -0.5 * innerContainer.clientHeight) {
    translateY = -0.5 * innerContainer.clientHeight;
  }

  if (translateX < -0.5 * innerContainer.clientWidth) {
    translateX = -0.5 * innerContainer.clientWidth;
  }

  // update the zoom container's translate values
  // based on the original + delta, capped to the
  // container's width and height.
  $("#zoom-container").css("transform", "translate(" + (2*translateX) + "px, " + (2*translateY) + "px) scale(2)");

  // keep track of the updated values for the next
  // touchmove event.
  window.lastTranslateX = translateX;
  window.lastTranslateY = translateY;
};

// Drag start -- touch version
$("#container").on("touchstart", function(event) {
  if (!window.zoomedIn) {
    return true;
  }

  var xCursor = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientX;
  var yCursor = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY;

  handleDragStart(this, xCursor, yCursor);
});

// Drag start -- mouse version
$("#container").on("mousedown", function(event) {
  if (!window.zoomedIn) {
    return true;
  }

  var xCursor = event.clientX;
  var yCursor = event.clientY;

  handleDragStart(this, xCursor, yCursor);
});

// Drag end -- touch version
$("#inner-container").on("touchend", function(event) {
  if (!window.zoomedIn) {
    return true;
  }

  handleDragEnd();
});

// Drag end -- mouse version
$("#inner-container").on("mouseup", function(event) {
  if (!window.zoomedIn) {
    return true;
  }

  handleDragEnd();
});

// Drag move -- touch version
$("#inner-container").on("touchmove", function(event) {
  // prevent pull-to-refresh. could be smarter by checking
  // if the page's scroll y-offset is 0, and even smarter
  // by checking if we're pulling down, not up.
  event.preventDefault();

  if (!window.zoomedIn) {
    return true;
  }

  var xCursor = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientX;
  var yCursor = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY;

  handleDragMove(xCursor, yCursor);
});

// Drag move -- click version
$("#inner-container").on("mousemove", function(event) {
  // prevent pull-to-refresh. could be smarter by checking
  // if the page's scroll y-offset is 0, and even smarter
  // by checking if we're pulling down, not up.
  event.preventDefault();

  // if we aren't dragging from anywhere, don't move
  if (!window.zoomedIn || !window.dragStartX) {
    return true;
  }

  var xCursor = event.clientX;
  var yCursor = event.clientY;

  handleDragMove(xCursor, yCursor);
});

var zoomInTo = function(element) {
  console.log("applying zoom");

  var top = element.offsetTop;
  // the subtracted value here is to keep the letter in the center
  var left = element.offsetLeft - (0.25 * $("#inner-container")[0].clientWidth);

  var translateY = 0.5 * $("#zoom-container")[0].clientHeight - top;
  var translateX = 0.5 * $("#zoom-container")[0].clientWidth - left;

  $("#container").css("overflow", "scroll");
  $("#zoom-container").css("transform", "translate(" + (2*translateX) + "px, " + (2*translateY) + "px) scale(2)");
  window.translateY = translateY;
  window.translateX = translateX;

  window.zoomedIn = true;
}

var zoomOut = function() {
  console.log("resetting zoom");

  window.zoomedIn = false;
  $("#zoom-container").css("transform", "");
  $("#zoom-container").css("transition", "");
  window.dragStartX = null;
  window.dragStartY = null;
  window.dragMoveJustHappened = null;
  window.translateY = window.lastTranslateY;
  window.translateX = window.lastTranslateX;
  window.lastTranslateX = null;
  window.lastTranslateY = null;
}

$(".box").click(function(event) {
  var element = this;
  var zoomContainer = $("#zoom-container");

  if (!window.zoomedIn) {
    zoomInTo(element);
  }
});

$("#zoom-out").click(function(event) {
  zoomOut();
});
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#inner-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#zoom-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}
```

I pieced this together from another question ([Move (drag/pan) and zoom object (image or div) in pure js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252249/move-drag-pan-and-zoom-object-image-or-div-in-pure-js)), where the `width` and `height` are being changed. That doesn't quite apply in my case, because I need to zoom into a specific element on the page (with a lot boxes than in a 2x2 grid). The solution from that question (https://jsfiddle.net/j8kLz6wm/1/) shows the basic approach in pure JavaScript. If you have jQuery available, you can probably just use [`jquery.panzoom`](https://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/).