# when zoomed, div does not place scrollbars on certain cases

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

This is a simple HTML placeholder for a thing I am working on. 
You can ignore the rest (I hope!) and focus on this sole issue:

The zoom on the image works, and it focus on the quadrant you press on, as I want it to. But it only places top and bottom scroll bars if the zoom is made on the top left quadrant.

I want it to always show the scroll bars. What am I missing?

Thanks

```js
var images = ["Species_copy_number.png", "Species_coverage.png", "Species_distribution.png", "Gene_copy_distribution.png"];
var descriptions = ["cariño", "muis bueno", "caliente", "CABRÓN!"];
var titles = ["ay", "ay ay", "ay ay ay", "AY AY AY MI HIJJJJJJOOOOOOOOOOOOO"];
function changeImage(index){
    var img = document.getElementById("img_place");
    img.src = "Figures/" + images[index];
    document.getElementById("desc_place").textContent = descriptions[index];
    document.getElementById("subtitle").textContent = titles[index];
}
window.zoomedIn = false;
window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("img_wrapper");
    canvas.onclick = function(event){
        var imgWrapper = this, zoomContainer = document.getElementById("zoom-container");
        var imgPlace = document.getElementById("img_place");
        if (window.zoomedIn) {
            imgPlace.setAttribute("style", "transform :\"\"");
            window.zoomedIn = false;
        } else {
            var width = zoomContainer.offsetTop + zoomContainer.offsetWidth;
            var height = zoomContainer.offsetTop + zoomContainer.offsetHeight;
            var tro = (zoomContainer.offsetTop + event.clientY > height / 2) ? "bottom" : "top";
            tro += (zoomContainer.offsetLeft + event.clientX > width / 2) ? " right" : " left";
            imgPlace.setAttribute("style", "transform-origin: "+ tro + " 0px; transform: scale(2);");
            window.zoomedIn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body, html { height: 100%; }
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.flex-item {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}
.flex-item img{
    width: 100%;
}
span {
    min-width: 5em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
a {
    padding-left: 0.3em;
}
.img-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#zoom-container{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Mega title</h1>
<h2 id="subtitle">Title</h2>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
        <span>
            cenas<br>
            <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(0)">Img #1</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(1)">Img #2</a>
            cenas<br>
            <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(2)">Img #3</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(3)">Img #4</a>
        </span>
        <div id="zoom-container">
            <div id="img_wrapper" class="img-wrapper">
                <img id="img_place" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ddqvuwXBK5k/maxresdefault.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<h2>Description</h2>
<span id="desc_place">Description</span>
```

Comment: Make a JSFiddle and post the link here. It will help with debugging.

Comment: For some reason it does not run :/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vqtohkm8/1/

Comment: Works now here, for some reason the fiddle doesn't https://jsfiddle.net/vqtohkm8/5/

Comment: So have you solved it or not ?

Comment: the code runs here but the scrollbar issue remains

Answer (score 5):

The **coordinate system** starts from left upper corner of the parent element. Since you are transforming the origin of the image in your quadrant on click, you are starting it from a clipped point.

With regard to document flow directions, the top and left sides are the **block-start** and **inline-start sides** and browsers or UA behave as though content is clipped beyond that direction.

[From W3C specs: *Scrolling Origin, Direction, and Restriction*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#scrolling-direction)

> Due to Web-compatibility constraints ... UAs must clip the scrollable overflow region of scroll containers on the [**block-start**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/#block-start) and [**inline-start sides**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/#inline-start) of the box **(thereby behaving as if they had no scrollable overflow on that side)**.

[image: (CSS Writing Modes)]

There may be a JS hack. I am not sure.

Here are some work-arounds (with) better explanations.

- [CSS Transforms / JS to zoom into element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388485/using-css-transform-scale-to-zoom-into-an-element-without-cropping-maintainin)
- [Canvas Method](https://codepen.io/techslides/pen/zowLd)

---

The best I could think of in your case is to add this CSS for `.img-wrapper`

```
.img-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;    
  overflow: auto
}
```

and add `overflow: auto;` to `imgPlace.setAttribute()`in your last else statement

```
imgPlace.setAttribute("style", "transform-origin: "+ tro + " 0px; transform: scale(2);position: relative;overflow: auto;");
```

**That way you will get scroll bars in quadrant 1, 2 and 3. In the fourth quadrant scroll restriction will be enabled.**

Here is a [codepen edit of your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwOoYb)

Comment: I ran your codepen (linux, firefox 48) and the scrollbars appear but if you zoom on the bottom quadrants the scroll bar does not allow to scroll top

Comment: yeah. That is because of the scroll restrictions, transformed origin of the image and document flow direction. Updated the above explanation. Please check.

Comment: you can  have the image as a `background image` and change the values of `background-position` property via JavaScript instead of transforming origin. just an idea. what do you think?

Comment: Would that allow to scroll on the background?

Comment: Probably not. Your best bet would be to ditch the scroll idea and go with a Pan/Drag or Canvas method. Links updated in the post above.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create two new classes in css

```
.zoomed {
  transform:scale(2);
}
.scroll {
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Add some jquery code

```
$ ('#img_wrapper').click(function() {
var top = $('#img_place').height() / 2;
$('#img_place').toggleClass('zoomed');
$(this).toggleClass('scroll');
if ($('#img_place').hasClass('zoomed')) {
$('#img_place').css('top', top);
}
else {
$('#img_place').css('top', '0');
}
});
```

Here is [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cur3nttb/) chek out this.
Hope it's fine for you

Comment: Does not work properly, always zooms center top, and you can only scroll right, so the left part of the image is cropped and unreachable (using firefox 48 linux)

Comment: Here is [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cur3nttb/2/) updated fiddle. Hope it's fine for you

Comment: The zoom always goes to the top left quadrant, I want it to be applied to the quadrant where you click, and yet be possible to scroll to the remainder of the image